# ssh tunnel general process on a phone -used as vpn -user limitation failed

Tags: 20.04, ssh, vpn, openssh, sshd

I'm using a couple of vm's as an ssh tunnel-vpn for both android and iOS, using ssh clients on both OS's. so now i want to limit the number of sessions per each user in order for each user is limited to 1 session at a time. for example: let's say i created 20 users and enabled password authentication for these users ( user1 ,...user20 ).

I have already tried setting these limits to 1 in

`sshd_config: maxsessions=1, maxstartups =1`

and
`"* hard maxlogins 1" & "* soft maxlogins 1" in limits.conf`
my PAM settings are pretty straight forward too.

now the interesting part is that when I try to ssh into the vm with a user,let's say user10(ssh user10@server ), the limit works and I can not ssh to it on any other devices, but for ssh clients on the phone (that is used for only tunneling the phone and using the ssh ass a vpn) it doesn't . I can tunnel more than 100 phones when using this vm.

basically I want each user to be able to tunnel only one device at a time and not any more than that, sort of a device limit for the connection

I reckoned the problem is that maybe the issue stems from something I don't know or am not considering.

I wondered maybe the process for tunneling a phone using ssh clients is far different from ssh-ing to a VM

apps I've used on phone: napsternet for iOS and matsuri for Android

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Touch is supported by [UBPorts](https://ubports.com/) and now called [Lomiri](https://lomiri.com/), its not on-topic here*

Comment: @guiverc oh i see, honestly  i  just added the tag cuz it was recommended , else it's just an ubuntu/sshd related issue

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 with the *year.month* format used) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life..  Run `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your status, and you'll note EOSS has occurred. Some architectures will continue to get upgrades during May 2023 due to a Canonical decision to extend life (*by one month*), but your system is effectively EOSS now & you should plan your upgraded asap.  EOSS for all 18.04 is 31-May-2023.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support